# Set Liferay Theme Bootstrap Variables based on color-sheme

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

I created a liferay 7.3 theme based on the theme-generator (yo liferay-theme) and want to support color schemes.
In the past, I set the boostrap/clay variables in _clay_variables.scss such as:

```
$primaray: #ff0000;
$secondary: #00ff00;
$theme-colors: (
   primary: $primary,
   secondary: $secondary
)
```

and my bootstrap theme will have the appropriated color theme.
Is possible to somehow overwrite $primaray or $seconday variables based on the liferay look-and-feel color-sheme? How can this be archived?

Comment: Not an answer: Have you looked at stylebooks? They seem to be "the way to go" from 7.3 onwards - and maybe in combination with a theme (even though a theme might not even be necessary with the classic theme and an appropriate stylebook)

Comment: Thank you @OlafKock for the comment. I did not used 7.3 Stylebooks so far and need some time to evaluate if this approach fits my needs. The article looks promising